# WordPress Dashboard not working correctly

Tags: windows, wordpress, sql-server-2008

I have recently installed wordpress on my Windows 7 machine for use with IIS7.5 and SQL Server 2008. The install went in with no issues and everything fired up correctly but I have some really major issues.

1.) In my dashboard when clicking on Posts>All Posts, my list of posts is empty and yet the links at the top (All, Published,  Drafts) all show as having counts against them. I can browse to these post by entering the URL in directly to the browser but can't see them through the dashboard. The posts don't show up through the search either. This is also the same behavior for media libs too. It says the files are there but can be seen in the list.

2.) When trying to upload images I have two issues. The first is that when I try to upload an image with default settings from install I was getting a message like "Missing a temporary folder". I know there are a load of posts on this but none of the fixes have worked. I used the PHP Info file to get the default directory which was "C:\windows\temp". So I tried to override it in the PHPconfig using the **upload_tmp_dir** directory but it didn't change. So I changed the permission on the folder to allow "IUSR" and IIS users read and wright access but now I get the message "An error occurred in the upload". The weird thing is when I look in the wp-content/uploads folder, some of my images are there but can't be seen through the dashboard.

Can anyone help. I have search for hours trying to find resolutions but nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved both of the issues above. I cannot write the resolutions here as they are quite long winded but for anyone who comes across the same issues please review my blog post here: http://blog.building-blocks.com/installing-wordpress-on-windows-using-sql-server-2008-r2-part-1

Regards